# After setting a new future value in setState method; Before the data renews that future still has data

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I am basically trying to re-fetch the data from api and show it on screen using **RefreshIndicator**. In **onRefresh** method of the widget I set future of my **FutureBuilder** widget to a new value. However until the data gets returned by the api AsyncSnapShot in FutureBuilder never has a null a data again. It still show the OLD DATA when there is a fetch request for the new data. What I want it to do is to show a LoadingProgressIndicator to show instead of old data. Like the code did at first time. Here's my code

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("GDC Saudia"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () {
          return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0), () {
            setState(() {
              _quotesFuture = _getData(Endpoint.all);
            });
          });
        },
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(),
            AnimatedBuilder(child: GestureDetector(),),
            SizedBox(),
            FutureBuilder(
                future: _quotesFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Some error occured",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 32),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Expanded(
                        child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                  }
                  return Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (_, index) => AnimatedTranslationWidget(
                          duration: 1 + (index * 0.10),
                          child: QuoteCard(
                            quote: snapshot.data[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Here is the initState method

```
 Future<List<Quote>> _quotesFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _quotesFuture = _getData(Endpoint.all);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Quote>> _getData(Endpoint point) async =>
      await ApiService(API()).getEndpointsData(point);
```

I am just trying to refresh the content of the screen on OnRefresh Pull. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One drawback of futures is that you **cannot** execute the future again.

That is where streams are introduced. I suggest you to implement it using streams in dart.

Have a look [at this great Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZkGT8WkjdA)

Comment: I did make Stream<Future<List<Quotes>>> but it had the same effect.

Comment: And with future data did change meaning new future did re-built. But the future builder snapshot always had value